# Modal not opening

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

Im pretty new to coding and i've been trying to make a wepage that works as a user interface. In the UI there is buttons that is suppose to launch application using javaScript (not quite there yet) and 2 buttons that open modals on top of the current screen: Help and Settings.

Code for the modals:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#settings">
  <img src="img/settings.png" alt="" class="img-circle">
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#help">
  <img src="img/help.png" alt="" class="img-circle">
</button>


<div id="settings" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Settings</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4> Tethering</h4>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="wlanName" size="15">
        <label>Passphrase:</label>
        <input type="text" id="passPhrase" size="15">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="enableTethering()">Enable tethering</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="disableTethering()">Disable tethering</button>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

  <div id="help" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Help</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          *CONTENT TO BE MADE*
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The issue is, that the first modal works fine. Second modal only "dims" the background, but the modal it self wont come visible. In this case, the settings work fine, but the help does not. If swap the help code before the settings code, then help works and settings does not.

But, when i coded it, i had typo. The second div of the modal were typed
     instead of  but everything worked, after i switched the

Comment: you are missing ending **</div>** bellow the close button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#settings">
            <img src="img/settings.png" alt="" class="img-circle">
        </button>
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#help">
            <img src="img/help.png" alt="" class="img-circle">
        </button>
   
        <div id="settings" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Settings</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4> Tethering</h4>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="wlanName" size="15">
                    <label>Passphrase: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="passPhrase" size="15">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="enableTethering()">Enable tethering</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="disableTethering()">Disable tethering</button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>

          



      
    <div id="help" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Help</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                      *CONTENT TO BE MADE*
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
```

You forgot to mention `</div>`

hope this works.

Comment: *facepalm* 

That was it... Thank you :)

Comment: if it helps you to get output which you want then mark it as answer so that question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You had missing closing tags for your modal divs.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#settings">
  <img src="img/settings.png" alt="" class="img-circle">
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#help">
  <img src="img/help.png" alt="" class="img-circle">
</button>


<div id="settings" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" >

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Settings</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4> Tethering</h4>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="wlanName" size="15">
        <label>Passphrase:</label>
        <input type="text" id="passPhrase" size="15">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="enableTethering()">Enable tethering</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="disableTethering()">Disable tethering</button>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div id="help" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Help</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          *CONTENT TO BE MADE*
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```